# Facebook iOS Integration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, feed

I have recently implemented the Facebook functionality to post an URL as explained in [iOS Facebook Development](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/)

It's the same as explained.

After I've signed up on Facebook and set my app key, I started the iPhone simulator and authorized as explained on Facebook. After that the Mobile Safari didn't jump back to my app (Because I don't want Facebook to jump back. Later I want to do that calling a webpage by my own). So I just started it again (activated because of iOS 4.2).

After that, I switched to the where I post a default URL.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

NSString *communityURL = @"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com";

[params setObject:communityURL forKey:@"link"];

[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Normally it should bring up a dialog with this parameters, but it just showed an error:

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 25 at column 35: xmlParseEntityRef: no name
>
> Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

When I debug into the method which calls the dialog, I got the URL, which will be called.
When executing this URL in a web browser, it works.

Why doesn't it work?
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok what I did is simply add

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"];
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"Share Item with Google url ;)"];

// Get the ShareKit action sheet
SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

// Display the action sheet

[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

And that's what I do.

If someone needs help, please feel free!!

Br
Nic

Comment: For all who don't know where to find this SHKItem, just look here http://www.getsharekit.com/. This is an external libray, which can easily be used.

Comment: And don't forget to set the settings in SHKConfig for your App.

Comment: I'm tinkering with sharekit now - it appears that it has no support for IOS 5.x or ARC.   Is that correct?  Is there a workaround?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't use the ARC but i guess, if the guy(s) who programmed the share kit will create a library or create a new branch, that is compatible with ARC, it would be fine. But you could also try to just remove every release and autorelease method from the source, than i guess it will be compatible. But in total i don't have any problems regarding to iOS 5.x with share kit. But there was once a problem with closing some modal view controllers. The guy from share kit already fixed the problem and you will only have to update share kit! Did it help? Br

Comment: Thanks, Nic.  Still tinkering with both sharekit (hundreds of ARC errors to fix), as well as the native fb sdk.  Really only need fb integration but following their tuts always seems to end in some mismatch of versions as well (xcode, storyboards, etc...)  fb tuts seem outdated as sharekits do...   Really surprising that there is not more guidance for the current iOS 5.1, storyboard, no ARC environment.  thanks for your comments though.

Comment: I've just updated to Xcode 4.3.2 and in the description it says that they changed their ARC. Maybe this could be your solution. Br

Answer (score 0):

i didn't figure out what it was, but i came up with an other solution.
I now use [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/). It's easy to use and it handles all alone. I try to post some sourcecode snipets asap.

For those, who have the same problem and don't want to use another API, try to do what ever the facebook documentation tells you.

Br
Nic

Comment: I needed to modify some Sharekit Objects, so it works for my solution, but the implementation should normally fill all gaps, a iOS Programmer needs to post something on facebook.